# How to populate a treeview from a sql database table that does not have an ID or ParentID column?

Tags: c#, sql, treeview

I'm working on WinForm app in VS2008, I have a sql table that is in the following order:

```
Region | Contract  | Name
-------------------------
South  | Miami     | John
South  | Miami     | Peter
South  | Calafornia| Brock
North  | New York  | Josh
```

I would like to display it in a treeview as follows:

```
South
  --Miami
      --John
      --Peter
  --Calafornia
      --Brock
North
  --New York
      --Josh
```

I can get it done by reading the database table and making a `datatable` that looks like this:

```
ID  | ParentID | Description
-----------------------------
1   |          | South
2   | 1        | Miami
3   | 1        | Calafornia
4   | 2        | John
5   | 2        | Peter
6   | 3        | Brock
```

I would like to know if that is the only way to get the data from the table into a treeview or can someone help me with a more intunative method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also iterate through all the rows returned ordered alphabetically on each level field, and if a level field changes its value, create a new branch on that level.

You always keep the last row in memory and compare the fields from right to left.